# Convergence of CG method, number of eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-explanation, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to fix this proof of a lemma that I did't correctly write:

> If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ symmetric positive definite with $m$
>   different Eigenvalues $\lambda_j$, then the Conjugate gradient method for $A$ converges in
>   a maximum of $m$ iterations.

Let $U_m=K_m(r_0,A)=\langle r_0,Ar_0,\dots,A^{m-1}r_{0}\rangle$ the m'th Kyrolv space. We want to show $U_m=U_{m+1}$ (why)

For $v_j$ the Eigenvektors to the $m$ different Eigenvalues, we can write $r_0$ as:
$$r_0=\sum_j \gamma_j v_j \in V_m= \langle v_1,\dots,v_m\rangle$$
Let $z\in V_m$, so $z=\sum_j \alpha_j v_j$. Then we have
$$Az=\sum_j \alpha_j A v_j=\sum_j \alpha_j \lambda_jv_j=\sum_j \beta_j v_j \in V_m.$$

I don't understand why this gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In extension of the last equation you get 
$$
A^iz=\sum_jα_jA^iv_j=\sum_jα_jλ_j^ivj\in V_m \implies K_i(z,A)\subset V_m.
$$
So as the chain of Krylov spaces has to increase in dimension until it becomes stationary at $U_k=U_{k+1}=...$, one has necessarily $k\le m$, as all these spaces are subspaces of the $m$-dimensional subspace $V_m$. At most $k=m$, so that in every case $U_{m+1}=U_m$.

Comment: And this means the CG method terminates? why?

Comment: The CG method in every step produces the point with the smallest residuum that is contained in the Krylov subspace of that step. As the solution is an element of $K_n(r_0,A)$ by Cayley-Hamilton, it is also contained in $K_m(r_0,A)$, as these are the same spaces under the given assumptions. And the point with residuum zero has obviously the smallest possible residuum in any measure. Thus iterate $m$ is already the exact solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't understand this in the lecture very well.